# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not passing property values to bean

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a very simple requirement which has turned complicated and I have spent a day on it without any luck. I have a properties file called `jdbc.properties` which has the DB connection details. I need to create a datasource connection with the values from the property file. The property value is not being passed right now, leading to DB connectivity error messages. If I hardcode the property values in the bean, it works. My spring config file `myBatis.DataSource.config.xml` looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="newProperty"    
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" lazy-  
    init="true">
        <property name="locations" value="jdbc.properties.${env}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="newDataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" depends-
    on="newProperty" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="username" value="${DBUSER}" />
        <property name="password" value="${DBPASSWORD}" />
        <property name="url" value="${DBURL}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DRIVER}" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="false" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="2" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory"   class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"   
      value="com/automation/config/oneValidation-config.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="newDataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean  class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.automation.config" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The value for `${env}` is passed as a system property to the class. The code for the class is as below:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ExecutorType;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MybatisTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MybatisTest mybatisTest = new MybatisTest();
        mybatisTest.testSelectQuery();
    }

    public void testSelectQuery(){

        String resource = "oneValidation-config.xml";
        SqlSession session = null;
        try {
            ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myBatis.DataSource.config.xml");
            SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = (SqlSessionFactory)context.getBean("sqlSessionFactory");
            session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
            System.out.println("Test" + 
                   session.selectOne("com.automation.config.PostingMapper.
                   countByExample",null));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(session != null)
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is as shown below and is sue to the fact that the `${DBUSER}`, `${DBPASSWORD}` fields are not being retrieved from the property file jdbc.properties:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause:                       
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC 
Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot 
create PoolableConnectionFactory (JZ00L: Login failed.  Examine the SQLWarnings chained 
to this exception for the reason(s).)
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran accross this as well.  In the mybatis documentation [here](https://mybatis.github.io/spring/mappers.html) I found why this happens.

From the source: "NOTE sqlSessionFactoryBean and sqlSessionTemplateBean properties were the only option available up to MyBatis-Spring 1.0.2 but given that **the MapperScannerConfigurer runs earlier in the startup process that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** there were frequent errors. For that purpose that properties have been deprecated and the **new properties sqlSessionFactoryBeanName and sqlSessionTemplateBeanName are recommended**."

Try changing your MapperScannerConfigurer bean from

```
<bean  class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">  
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.automation.config" />  
</bean>
```

to

```
<bean  class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">  
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.automation.config" />  
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<property name="locations" value="classpath:/yourFolderName/jdbc.properties"/>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I was doing that initially and when it didnt work, I changed to above.

Comment: @Vinod Madan Try to remove `lazy-init="true"` as well.

Comment: Removed lazy-init. Still no luck