# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers loading after parameterized DataSource bean

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-mybatis

At the top of my application context I declare a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

```
...
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties"/>
...
```

Later on I declare a datasource bean parameterized by properties from that properties file

```
<bean id="someDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="URL" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

During deployment I notice that the datasource bean is created and a connection is attempted to be established BEFORE the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is initialized.  That's causing my datasource parameterizations to not be populated.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Is there a specific order of creation for beans?  Are certain beans always initialized before others?  Is there a way to ensure that the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is loaded before all other beans?

Comment: It is loaded before all other beans unless you are using the datasource in some other bean that is needed very early on in your startup sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one of the beans I defined is a MapperScannerConfigurer for mybatis that references a sqlSessionFactory.

The MapperScannerConfigurer can initialize prior to any PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer if it's initialized with deprecated bean properties

To correct the behavior, the sqlSessionFactory has to be referenced using a different bean property.

See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477336/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-not-passing-property-values-to-bean/30936610#30936610) for more details

Comment: After three days of tracking this down in my own application, it all seems so simple now :) Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties"/>` ahead of `<context:annotation-config/>`

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties"/>
<context:annotation-config/>`

Comment: Ordering doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Gabriel J Thank you for the suggestion.  It turned out to be related to how a Mybatis related bean was created. You can see my post below and the related link if you're curious